# Ambiguous reference to member 'decode(_:forKey:)' swift4

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I am parsing a response that needs to be transformed from a dictionary on the server (which is a legacy data format) - to simply an array of strings on the client side. Therefore I am wanting to decode the key called 'data' as a dictionary, so i can iterate through the keys and create an array of strings on the client side.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws  {
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  do {
    let some_data_dictionary = try values.decode([String:Any].self, forKey: CodingKeys.data)

    for (kind, values) in some_data_dictionary {
      self.data_array.append(kind)  
    }
  } catch {
    print("we could not get 'data' as [String:Any] in legacy data \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is: `Ambiguous reference to member 'decode(_:forKey:)'`

Comment: `[String:Any]` doesn't conform to Codable. Post your json response from server

Comment: Oh God, the coding style!!!

Comment: @LeoDabus Better yet to say that `Codable` does not support `Any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Swift 'Codable' cant support Any or use of [String:Any], so using this post here [Swift 4 decodable nested json with random key attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607395/swift-4-decodable-nested-json-with-random-key-attributes)

I was able to make a struct for a class I wouldn't use called LegacyData, and then unpack the keys into an array of strings

```
    do
    {
      let legacy_data = try values.decode([String:LegacyData].self, forKey: CodingKeys.data)

      self.array = Array(legacy_data.keys)
    }
    catch
    {
      print("no legacy_data \(error) \n")
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you can also get this message if you try to decode an array of custom class, when the custom class does not conform to 'Codable'